# A very simple riddle

Tags: riddle

I can be used for access.

I, my Eastern and Western neighbors; We all live in order.

Some things that live right near me are: an insect, a question.

#### What am I?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer is:

> The letter "G" on a qwerty keyboard.

I can be used for access:

> well, it is a key, and keys let you access previously locked locations (credit goes to @wolfram42 for this reasoning), and I noticed that ctrl-g also brings up the search bar on chrome.

Me, my Eastern and Western neighbors all live in order

> FGH are in a row on the keyboard, one after the other, alphabetically.

Some things that live right near me: an insect,

> a B (Bee)

a question.

> a Y (why?)

also note:

> there is also a beverage neighbouring G, Tea (T). If you happen to live in AU or NZ, you may have notice the energy drink (V) also.

Comment: apparently ctrl-g is another hotkey for searching (at least for chrome). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 11):

I know this isn't the right answer, but it was too good to pass up:

> Tur-*key*

I can be used for access:

> A key is used for access.

I, my Eastern and Western neighbors all live in order.

> Greece was named before Turkey, which was named before Armenia (ordered chronologically)

Some things that live right near me: an insect, a question.

Insect:

> Not sure, unless of course it's Buda-*pest*

Question:

> Will there be a cease fire in Syria?

Comment: Truly clever! I love it

Answer (score 10):

I don’t think this is the right answer, but it was too close not to share. Is it...

> The letter K on a keyboard

Reasoning:

> 1. It can be used as part of a password to access something.
>  2. It, along with its Eastern and Western neighbors (J and L), are in alphabetical order.
>  3. Also neighboring it on the keyboard are a back *tick* (insect) and a question mark.

Comment: Ooh, clever answer! :)

Comment: Regarding point 3: certainly not on my keyboard (backtick at top left, question mark at bottom right, k in middle right). This is quite location-dependent.

Answer (score 4):

Is it:

> The **Enter** key?

I can be used for access.

> Entering = Accessing

Me, my Eastern and Western neighbors all live in order.

> East of Enter key : 4,5,6,... West of Enter key: j,k,l,...

Some things that live right near me: an insect, a question

> Question key is near enter key and based on *@tjs352* answer: *back tick (insect)*

Answer (score 3):

Micsthepick's answer seems correct but there is no reasoning, so I'm adding it here:

> Answer: The G key.
>  
>  It can be used for access. (a key is a password)
>
>  East and west neighbours are in order: F G H are in order.
>
>  Near a question: Y = Why?   Near an insect: B = Bee

Comment: that would have been correct a few minutes ago :P

Comment: My post time and your edit time are nearly identical. Well played.

Comment: How is a key a password? A password might be considered a key, but generally a key is an object for opening a lock.

Comment: I used the word password for simplicity. When talking about encryption you use "keys" to access files. Of course now that you mention it. A physical key might be a better explanation since it unlocks doors so you can gain access

Answer (score 2):

Answer might be

> Elements of a horizontal navigation bar.

Reasons

> The western and eastern neighbors lie in order.
> The elements are used for accessing other pages.
> Near it you can find search bar where you can ask question (this site).
> Insect would refer to a spider web crawler .

Comment: Not bad, but not what I was thinking

Answer (score 2):

My answer..

> Stackoverflow

Reasons

> 1. you can access all kind of questions from east to west 
>  2. insect (bug) and question